# Build R container with specific packages

Tags: r, docker, podman, renv

In an effort to apply the MLOps "shift left" approach I switched from virtual environments to containers for each project. The thing is, that I want to take a record of the R packages' version that I use, so that when I build my container from a `Dockerfile` I have a container with al the right packages.

My current approach is to use the `renv` lockfile and call `renv::restore()` in the `Dockerfile`. This approach works but whenever I do a snapshot of the environment `renv` creates all other hooks such as the `renv` folder and the `.Rprofile` which are useless in my container since the only environment I have is the one of the container.

Is there a clever way to do it?

Comment: Would `devtools::install_version` work for you?

Comment: The problem is that I want also a record as `renv` does with the lock file, with `devtools::install_version` I need to take that record by myself and update it manually every time. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: That is correct. But you could write a helper function to query your attached namespace and print the results of loaded packages + version to a file in the same way `renv::snapshot` does. Then in the Dockerfile you can just run the 'restore' script.

Comment: If all you're doing is calling `renv::snapshot()`, then this extra infrastructure you're talking about shouldn't be getting written out. Can you share the entirety of the code you're using?

Comment: Thanks Kevin for reaching out, you mean both the `Dockerfile` and the R script?